# set width and height of canvas in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have an image background in my HTML5 canvas.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('#canvas1');
canvas.setBackgroundImage(
            'http://fabricjs.com/assets/jail_cell_bars.png',
             canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
       );
```

How to set dimensions of my canvas (width, height) to the dimensions of the background image?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use CSS or dom properties to set the dimensions of your canvas. If you know the dimensions of your image, you can do it in a stylesheet:

```
#canvas1 { width: XXXpx; height: YYYpx; }
```

Or in the dom:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="XXX" height="YYY"></canvas>
```

If the image is dynamic and want to set the dimensions in JS, you do something like this:

```
var image = new Image()
image.src = 'http://fabricjs.com/assets/jail_cell_bars.png';

image.onLoad = function () { 
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
};
```

Comment: glad it works. be careful though, if you don't use the `onLoad` callback, you do not wait for your browser to download the image, which means that when you'll try to get image.width and image.height, you'll get 0. Try with a bigger image that your browser has not cached yet, you'll see.

Comment: Note that **this answer does not pertain to the fabric.js plugin** like the question specified. It only pertains to generic HTML canvas elements. See the answer below by Calvin to set dimensions on a Fabric.Canvas element.

Answer (score 50):

I think the above answer does not use fabric.js, it uses normal canvas.

When you use fabric.js and its Fabric.Canvas class, the code should be:

```
image.onLoad = function() {
  var fabric_canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');
  fabric_canvas.setDimensions({width:image.width, height:image.height});
};
```

In my case,

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("test_fabric");
canvas.setDimensions({width:800, height:200});
```

The result is:

```
<canvas id="test_fabric" width="800" height="200" class="lower-canvas" style="position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 200px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
```

Both canvas.width and canvas.style.width are set.

Comment: I am searching how to set canvas.width and canvas.style.width respectively using Fabric.Canvas class. Could someone teach me the tips?

Comment: I found the answer:    canvas.setDimensions({width:800, height:200},{backstoreOnly:true});
    canvas.setDimensions({width:'800px', height:'200px'},{cssOnly:true});

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. Indeed it uses the fabric.js canvas, not the HTML5 canvas directly.

Answer (score 5):

These work as well!

```js
canvas.setWidth(500);
canvas.setHeight(400);
```

Comment: On the new beta, `setWidth` and `setHeight` are deprecated and replace with `.width` and `.height`; however, while you can get the values, when you set them they don't do anything. If you use the `setWidth` it creates issues with webpack